# Multiple methods named 'edges' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5

This code worked in X-Code 4.6 but fails in X-Code 5:

```
NSMutableArray *a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];

for (int k=0; k<4; k++) {
    int e = arc4random_uniform(3)+1;

    if (arc4random_uniform(2)>0) {
        e *= -1;
    }

    [a addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:e]];
}

if (i>0) {
    int l = [arrayPieces count]-pieceNumber;
    int e = [[[[arrayPieces objectAtIndex:l] edges] objectAtIndex:1] intValue]; //CAUSES ERROR
    [a replaceObjectAtIndex:3 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:-e]];
}

if (j>0) {
    int e = [[[[arrayPieces lastObject] edges] objectAtIndex:2] intValue];//CAUSES ERROR
    [a replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:-e]];
}
```

I also get the following error associated to the same code:

Bad receiver type 'UIRectEdge' (aka 'enum UIRectEdge')

...but I have no reference to 'UIRectEdge' in my project.

I've searched for similar cases of these errors but nothing seemed close enough to fix the issue that I was able to try.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the same problem as in this [Bad receiver type UIRectEdge and Multiple methods named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176046/bad-receiver-type-uirectedge-and-multiple-methods-named)

I guess your project is also originally from https://github.com/AndreaBarbon/Puzzle-iOS

What I did to get it running in Xcode 5.0.2 was to search the whole project for "edges" and replace every instance with "my_edges" (without quotes) and then it worked.

The problem is that "edges" has been added to the uikit in Xcode5/iOS7, that is why you get the error.

Answer (score 1):

The 'edges' property returns a UIRectEdge. If you have a custom class inside 'arrayPieces' that has its own getter called 'edges', try casting the object like this:

```
int e = [[[((MYCUSTOMOBJECT*)[arrayPieces objectAtIndex:l]) edges] objectAtIndex:1] intValue]; //CAUSES ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the assignment to `e` with the following:

```
int e = [[[((PieceView *)[arrayPieces objectAtIndex:l]) edges] objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
```